# php,python reading xml tag along with comments

Tags: php, dom

I have a xml file, I want read node value along with comments before the tag and move to the mysql database. I have tried with DOM, i can read all comments in a separate array and node values in separate array can't match exact comment to exact node value.tried in PHP can any one help in PHP or python

```
<ig:prescribed_property property_ref="0161-1#02-012537#1" is_required="true" combination_allowed="false" one_of_allowed="false">
            <dt:controlled_value_type representation_ref="0161-1#04-000006#1">
                <!-- NOT PROVIDED(Code:C,Table:AB22) -->
                <dt:value_of_property value_ref="0161-1#07-006593#1"/>
                <!-- PROVIDED(Code:B,Table:AB22) -->
                <dt:value_of_property value_ref="0161-1#07-006627#1"/>
            </dt:controlled_value_type>
</ig:prescribed_property>
```

eg:-0161-1#07-006593#1 ->NOT PROVIDED(Code:C,Table:AB22)

like this i want to read, in java we can do this with lexicalhandler and contenthandler

Comment: Try with [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: we can use sax parser but how to get comments